# Two tables, same Attributes unable to count,

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, phpmyadmin

I am working on Two table together for count how many SKU.

As I'm able to sum them up in how much amount with no problem. but I need a count on how many QTY in SKU.

I am able to get a count in SKU in one table only but unable to do two table. I have tried UNION SELECT but nothing working

```
SELECT
     transaction_type, sku, count(quantity_purchased) as SKU_ORDER

FROM
    settlements_qty_test
WHERE
        transaction_type = 'order'
        AND amount_description = 'Principal'
        AND amount_type = 'ItemPrice'   

UNION SELECT
     transaction_type, sku, count(quantity_purchased) as SKU_ORDER

FROM
    settlements_qty_test1
WHERE
        transaction_type = 'order'
        AND amount_description = 'Principal'
        AND amount_type = 'ItemPrice'   

GROUP BY sku 
ORDER BY sku
```

I have used this similar method for how much, and seems it working fine but not this one. Seems I am missing something?

I am still rookie MySQL.

Comment: Don't you want `SUM()` instead of `COUNT()`?

Comment: I have done with Sum and Count but both getting same results.

Comment: I hope you realize that `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses apply only to the second `SELECT`.

Comment: Yes, you are right as I just aware of it a half hour before you mention it, I was reading on MySQL document.

Comment: `SUM` will get a larger quantity if `qty` is bigger than 1.

Comment: @mustaccio, yes for the `GROUP BY`. But the `ORDER BY` applies to the whole query (the UNION of the two SELECTs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to fetch all affected records of both tables using UNION ALL and then COUNT the records. (I'm not sure if you want to COUNT records or to SUM quantities.)

Notice you should add `transaction_type` to the GROUP BY clause.

If you want you can move the WHERE clause to the main query.

```
SELECT transaction_type, sku, COUNT(quantity_purchased) as SKU_ORDER
FROM   (
        SELECT transaction_type, sku, quantity_purchased
        FROM   settlements_qty_test
        WHERE  transaction_type = 'order'
        AND    amount_description = 'Principal'
        AND    amount_type = 'ItemPrice'   
        UNION ALL
        SELECT transaction_type, sku, quantity_purchased
        FROM   settlements_qty_test1
        WHERE  transaction_type = 'order'
        AND    amount_description = 'Principal'
        AND    amount_type = 'ItemPrice'   
       ) t1
GROUP BY transaction_type, sku
ORDER BY sku;
```

Comment: That is perfect, If I want another add new column, like Transaction type='refund', do I write it on From Section () t1 or new section as ()t2?

Comment: You should add it in both UNION selects, in the outer select and in GROUP BY section.  If have any problem add a new question and post the link as a comment in this answer.